# All functions not implemented error

Tags: contract-development, contract-debugging

I have a complex structure of various contracts using various interfaces in solidity.

When I want to deploy the contract that runs all the others; I have the following error appearing in remix IDE:

```
This contract does not implement all functions and thus cannot be created.
```

I have been banging my head against my code for two days now; reviewing each functions, where they were used and how they were used. But I can't manage to find the specific function(s) not being implemented.

If you could please take a look at my code:
https://github.com/mGrossSRT/ERC777Issue

EDIT: I know it might seem like a beginner's mistake, but I have deployed tons of contracts for my application and those contracts have been used; SO, it's really an issue I have on a specific set of contracts and not just a noobs mistake.

Thank you in advance.

Mikael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is internal constructor in `ERC777ERC20BaseToken`, should be public

Comment: Really, the simplest things are sometimes the hardest to see. Thanks!